# How to make Server Sent Events (SSE) work with PHP sessions?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, comet

I am using SSE events to push friend request count of a user from server to client. But when I do so, other pages of the website get stuck and keep on loading (probably due to user session lock). How can I push SSE event data to client and not make other pages wait when sessions are running?

I have an event listener at client side as follows:

```html
var evtSource = new EventSource("friend-req.php");
var eventList = $('#list'); //this is div's ID on xhtml page
$(document).ready(function(){
 
$(function(){
 evtSource.addEventListener("requests", function(e) {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");
     
  var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
  newElement.innerHTML = "friend request count: " + obj.count;
  eventList.append(newElement);
 }, false);
});
});
```

On the server side I'm using an event while loop (as suggested by numerous articles on SO). First I get the current session user's friend request count from database, and then push it against the event 'requests' (for which client is listening).

```php
<?php

//friend-req.php file

session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
include_once 'db.php';

$db = new db();

while (1) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $q = "select count(*) num from requests where status = 1 and id = $user";

    $result = $db->select($q) or die("Query Failed:" . $db->last_error);

    if($result)
    {
        $r = $db->get_row($result);
        echo "event: requests\n";
        echo 'data: {"count": "' . $r['num'] . '"}';
        echo "\n\n";
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
}

?>
```

The problem is that when I run the client script, it runs fine, but none of my other pages loads. I've searched for the solution but haven't found any satisfactory answer neither here at SO nor at other websites. Tell me how can I send server side events with sessions and not make other pages wait (or if there's any flaw in the approach/better way to do so)

Comment: How did you overcome this issue ?? Did you make the other pages to load?? Bcos I am also facing same issue w.r.t SSE.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in "`session_start()`": every session locks a file in the server, so no other script can start using the same session (they all hang on their "`session_start()`" call) until the the first script ends and/or releases the lock. Your script should read the $user outside the loop and then call `session_commit()`, so other script can run. Remember that session locking always prevents parallel execution of scripts: always call `session_commit()` in your script if you've finished reading or modifying your session variables, so other script can run while the first finishes his elaboration (google around for other more elaborate solutions). This is very important, for example, if your browser does a lot of asynchronous ajax calls to your `php` code using sessions: without "`session_commit()`" you'll see your server respond to the requests one at the time without any parallelism